# GWT: Where is RichTextToolbar?

Tags: gwt, toolbar, richtext

I wrote simple GUI page:

```
public class Test01 {
     RootPanel r = RootPanel.get();
     public Test01() {
         RichTextArea richTextArea = new RichTextArea();
         r.add(richTextArea, 85, 134);
         richTextArea.setSize("412px", "260px");
     }
}
```

and when I run it, I see simple rectangle for RichTextArea. But there are numerous buttons around it in the sample, for example button to make bold font and etc. Where are all of them in my case? In the sample code I see the usage of RichTextTollbar class where is it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RichTextToolbar` is in the Showcase sample from the GWT SDK:
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.4.0/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/content/text/RichTextToolbar.java

Answer (score 0):

That what you want is not implemented in GWT, RichTextArea only gives you the ability to change those things.

What you're looking for is something like this:

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-html-editor/

Those are community made widgets.